# My array has only one item from pivot table

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

With this code :

```
$evenements = Year::with(['evenements' => function($query) {
    return $query->orderBy('mnemonique');
}])
    ->orderBy('id')
    ->get();
```

I get that:

```
5 => array:7 [▼
    "id" => 62
    "name" => "Congé"
    "mnemonique" => "Congé"
    "color" => "#bcbcbc"
    "created_at" => "2021-07-13T14:16:04.000000Z"
    "updated_at" => null
    "pivot" => array:2 [▼
        "year_id" => 1
        "evenement_id" => 62
```

The problem is that pivot should have 10 items and not only 2 because the event 62 is in 5 years

[image: Table Years]

[image: Table evenements]

[image: 5 records and not only 1]

This is the models code:

Events model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Evenement extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name','mnemonique','color'];

    //DD 18/07/21 Une année peut avoir plusieurs events 
    public function years()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Year::class, 'evenement_year', 'evenement_id', 'year_id'); 
    }
}
```

Year model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Year extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    public function evenements()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Evenement::class, 'evenement_year', 'year_id', 'evenement_id');
    }
}
```

This is the content of $query :

```
    Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany {#260 ▼
  #table: "evenement_year"
  #foreignPivotKey: "year_id"
  #relatedPivotKey: "evenement_id"
  #parentKey: "id"
  #relatedKey: "id"
  #relationName: "evenements"
  #pivotColumns: []
  #pivotWheres: []
  #pivotWhereIns: []
  #pivotWhereNulls: []
  #pivotValues: []
  +withTimestamps: false
  #pivotCreatedAt: null
  #pivotUpdatedAt: null
  #using: null
  #accessor: "pivot"
  #query: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder {#1478 ▶}
  #parent: App\Year {#1474 ▶}
  #related: App\Evenement {#1475 ▶}
}
```

I don't know how to feed pivot array ? Do you have any idea ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Show us the full image of the database, not some rows as we can't see the columns' names...

Comment: I changed the picture, we can see the name of the columns now, sorry

Answer (score 1):

You must specify extra columns in your relationship using `withPivot`; since I do not know your column names (cropped in image), I will just give an example:

```php
class Year extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    public function evenements()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Evenement::class, 'evenement_year', 'year_id', 'evenement_id')
            ->withPivot(["someField1", "someFiled2"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I edit my question and added some photos of my tables.  Like you can see, all fields are from the 3 tables (included in the pivot table as foreign key).

Comment: They are no extra columns, just fields from my 3 tables.

Comment: I tried to apply your reply, but I still have only 2 items for one record.